MQ Client Queue consumer throwing continuous exception as an MQ server down
My application having MQ Java client 9.0.4.0 to MQ server 9.1.0.*
In some events where MQ server down my MQ client start throwing continuous exceptions.
I am looking for what client configuration can be use to avoid such scenarios where continuous exception keep filling log and disk space in case left un noticed.
Below are top exceptions details - there are slightly more with long wrapped exception details which not mentioned here.
202x-xx-13 15:18:17,521 ERROR [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.consumer.dClient~JmsConsumer~xxx.BW_TMATCH.CAM.ALLOC] [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.consumer.d] Error on process message: error - JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'xxx.BW_TMATCH.CAM.ALLOC'.
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
2024-xx-13 15:18:17,521 INFO  [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.consumer.dClient~JmsConsumer~xxx.BW_TMATCH.CAM.ALLOC] [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.a.b] Rollback transactionContext: null
2024-xx-13 15:18:17,522 WARN  [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.consumer.dClient~JmsConsumer~xxx.BW_TMATCH.CAM.ALLOC] [com.xxx.fixengine.jms.client.consumer.d] Failed transaction rollback
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009
MQ client as an Queue connecting with basic arguments and below as connection factory being in action com.rbs.gbm.futures.stp.fix.jms.ConfigurableMQQueueConnectionFactory
for some event in case MQ server goes down my MQ client start throwing continuous exceptions until server gets up again itself.
I am looking for some client settings or api changes which stop this breakdown exceptions and this should be controlled by either some limited number of times or not at all

Looks like you have a loop in your code, that should be breaking out, maybe after x failures, or t mins without a good connection. If you share your loop code, we can show you how to use a count or timer or both to break out.

It would be helpful if you could show your application code.
I think you have few options here:

Catch the MQException and if the reason code is 2009 exit out of the loop (which you seem to be having).

Use reconnect option on connection factory. The reconnect option enables the MQ JMS library to reconnect to queue manager if there are connection problems, like a network problem causes the connection to queue manager to break. You can also set a timeout on how long the MQ JMS library to continue reconnection attempts.


For example:
cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();      
// Reconnect to queue manager
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR); 
// Reconnection timeout 
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1000);


Thanks for the response. I have not applied reconnect as suggested instead i am depending on third party library to get with MQ.
